# After Upgrading Swift 2.3 to 3 TableView Doesn't Working Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I've social media application in AppStore, I was writed it in Swift 2.3 when we needed an update for application we had to update our code 2.3 to 3 and I've made it by XCode but there was lots of errors and I've fixed by myself. Everything working well after all. But except one thing. I've live feed in main tab. There is a Cells in TableView. In every cell I've readmoretextview to compress the text like linkedin or instagram etc. It was working fine before Swift 3 but now sometimes when user clicks readmore cell changes the height but table doesn't updates itself. I can't updae like this. It's not doing that everytime but it's a problem for our application quality. So there is a video and code, you can watch it and understand what is the problem.

**Here is The Code**
[image: Here is The Code]

[Here is The Video](https://youtu.be/RAJ4MxI2fLM)

Comment: Wow, 329 warnings is heavy. And the `nil` checking of the table views is redundant. With optional chaining the methods are not called if the object is `nil`.

Comment: It has appeared after upgrading to swift 3, I'll handle it but now I've bigger problem than it, thanks for warn :)

Comment: This is not my problem, it's working i need that checking

Comment: I know that's not related to your issue but believe me, you don't need that checking.

Comment: Okay I'll fix that, thanks :)